# Is there is any solution for displaying sqlite database into my website using python flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Im creating web app for Fetching rss feed using python and flask. I can able to store feeds in sqlite database but I cant display it in my website im try some piece of code but its not routing to that website but app is running and fetching rss feed.please help me solve this problem

I have no idea for that except these code please help me!

This is the code im using.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def post_in_db(title):
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM feeds WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM feeds WHERE title =?)",[title])
    exist = c.fetchone()
    if exist is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

urllist = list()
count = 0
with open('urlList.txt') as fp:
    urllist = fp.read().splitlines()

def insertPost():
    for i in range(0,len(urllist)):
        parse_feed(urllist[i])

def parse_feed(url):
    feed= feedparser.parse(url)

    for post in feed.entries:
        if not post_in_db(post.title):
            data_entry(post.title, post.summary, post.link, post.published)

@app.route('/', defaults={'entries': 100})
def index():
    db_query = "select * from feeds limit %d" % entries
    res = db.engine.execute(db_query)
    return render_template("index.html", feeds=res.fetchall())
```

And my HTML code is

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>summary</th>
            <th>link</th>
            <th>datestamp</th>
        </tr>
        {% for user in feeds %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ user[0] }}</td>
                <td>{{ user[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ user[2] }}</td>
                <td>{{ user[3] }}</td>
              </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

what to do for routing and displaying in website.

i'm expecting to display the fetched feeds in sqlite database to my website

Comment: do some debugging to pinpoint what is not working. is it reading database? file? showing data in the template?

Comment: when i run this code its not  its doesnot give any error and im finally using this code     @app.route('/index.html') 
           def get_from_db():    
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM feeds')    
 return render_template('index.html', rows = c.fetchall())                                                but its not working im using shedule timing to update the feed when im using this code its not working and im not using this it directed to html page but it gives  url not found

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are doing `{% for user in users %}` when in the backend you have sent the variable `feeds` down to the view not users?

if the SQL query is fetching results back as expected you would generally use this to display the data.

```
{% for feed in feeds %}

{{ feed }} 

{% endfor %}
```

So the data is within the variable feeds from looking at your backend code.

Based on your new code provided please try the route like this:

```py
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    con = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    db = con.cursor()
    feeds = db.execute("SELECT * FROM feeds")
    feed=feeds.fetchall()
    conn.close()

    return render_template("index.html", feed=feed)
```

In your view try:

```py
{% for f in feed %}

{{ f }} 

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: im edited with  user as feed but it running and showing 404 error but i did all are right

Comment: What is showing a 404 error? can you please show us the error?

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: Im getting html file but now im not able to fetch the database details in website this is the code im using please help me!                                                                                     @app.route("/")
@app.route("/index", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    con = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    db = con.cursor()
    feeds = db.execute("SELECT * FROM feeds")
    return render_template("index.html", feed=feeds.fetchall())

c.close()
conn.close()

Comment: Can you try this code please?(check answer) Or even better is your full app pushed to a repo somewhere i can review and advise better?

I have edited my answer since new comment on this

Comment: ok perfect did my answer help you fix the issue or what is something else?

Comment: its gives me some idea little about it